# How to convert []byte to C hex format 0x...?

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    str := hex.EncodeToString([]byte("go"))
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

this code return `676f`. How I can print C-like `0x67, 0x6f` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any function in the `hex` module that would achieve what you want. However, we can use a custom buffer to write in our desired format.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    originalBytes := []byte("go")

    result := make([]byte, 4*len(originalBytes))

    buff := bytes.NewBuffer(result)

    for _, b := range originalBytes {
        fmt.Fprintf(buff, "0x%02x ", b)
    }

    fmt.Println(buff.String())

}
```

Runnable example: https://goplay.space/#fyhDJ094GgZ

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that produces the result as specified in the question.  Specifically, there's a ", " between each byte and no trailing space.

```
p := []byte("go")

var buf strings.Builder
if len(p) > 0 {
    buf.Grow(len(p)*6 - 2)
    for i, b := range p {
        if i > 0 {
            buf.WriteString(", ")
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "0x%02x", b)
    }
}
result := buf.String()
```

The [strings.Builder](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder) type is used to avoid allocating memory on the final conversion to a string. Another answer uses bytes.Buffer that does allocate memory at this step.

The the builder is initially sized large enough to hold the representation of each byte and the separators. Another answer ignores the size of the separators.

[Try this on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QEzh2YI9tGW).

Comment: Thanks for the nuanced answer. I like your approach.

Comment: The strings.Builder vs bytes.Buffer thing is nuance.  Everything else is about correctness.